# Moving all certain texts in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, line, move

I am wondering how to move all the `> CONTEXT :` line to below `> BEGIN STRING`

```
> BEGIN STRING
> CONTEXT: Actors/2/nickname/
Thunderclap of Guren

> END STRING

> BEGIN STRING
> CONTEXT: Actors/3/name/
Terence
> END STRING

> BEGIN STRING
St. knight that has been stripped of his position by the conspiracy. In order to master the true chivalry
It has repeatedly wander training the country.
> CONTEXT: Actors/3/description/

> END STRING
```

I can't moving up line-by-line as it will take forever because I have tons of text just like above and I want to fix it all.

EDIT : So here's what I want :

Before :

```
> BEGIN STRING
St. knight that has been stripped of his position by the conspiracy. In order to master the true chivalry
It has repeatedly wander training the country.
> CONTEXT: Actors/3/description/

> END STRING
```

After :

```
> BEGIN STRING

> CONTEXT: Actors/3/description/
St. knight that has been stripped of his position by the conspiracy. In order to master the true chivalry
It has repeatedly wander training the country.
> END STRING
```

Comment: Please, show the desired output for your example. Plus, show what have you tried.

Comment: @Julio I've tried bookmarking all the > CONTEXT lines but I don't know how to move all of them up or down at the same time. And some > CONTEXT lines have to move up 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: How does the new line work? In the `after` It has moved even on top of `CONTEXT` Is that correct? All new lines (if exist) must me moved above `CONTEXT` even if they were below at first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following:

`^> BEGIN STRING(\r?\n)+(?!^> CONTEXT:)\K([\s\S]*?)(> CONTEXT:[^\r\n]*)((?:\r?\n)+)?\r?\n`

Replace by:

`$4$3$1$2`

[image]

Comment: Wow this is what I was looking for. Thanks a ton. This is what I meant when I try to explain the problem haha. Some of the >Context that's below were moved one by one. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @Julio , I have another problem, I don't know how to contact you personally. I hope you can help : [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757447/how-do-i-merge-2-text-files-into-one-file)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this easily, as text are not in regular pattern. But this can be achieved with notepadd++ or sublime or anytext editor , and I will love to use numbers or excel for moving columns after converting them to csv. I will recommend using a excel or nubmers(mac) for editing csv(after you convert you text file to csv). Here is what you may need to tweak to get your result.

- First I will convert text to csv format by adding commas after > Begin string, and before >context, after > end of context line, and before the >end string

You can achieve this by selecting similar text (cmd+d) in sublime and easily moving the cursor to the end and begining of line or you can you use find and replace function in any text editor and add comma wherever possible to make them display as different column when opening it in excel.

- Once you have added the commas to your text file,  save it as csv and open in excel.
- Then drag the column >Context (3rd column ) to after Begin strings(place it in second column) and save it again.
- Open that csv file you have edited in excel in text editor again and do re-formatting and find and replace to remove commas.

Hope this will help.

Comment: How do I select all the >Context lines and move it to the 2nd columns ? Do I have to select it one by one ? In case I'm doing something wrong, is the commas before >context like ,>context ?

Comment: First make a copy of your file (backup). In sublime text, you can select one text and then select all similar text by pressing (ctrl/cmd + D). Or you can use search and replace.
 search for-> ' >Begin String' and replace by ',>Begin String,' and remove the first comma in first line