# How do I merge 2 text files into one file?

Tags: input, text, text-files

Okay so, I want to merge 2 text files :

File 1 :

```
Firstline
ABCD
Thirdline

Fifthine
```

File 2 :

```
Firstline

Thirdline
EFGH
Fifthline
```

Expected output :

```
Firstline
ABCD
Thirdline
EFGH
Fifthline
```

I can't use `copy filea+fileb filec` with cmd because it just copy and paste one to another and merge it into one file.

Comment: If first file and second file have some data at (let's say) first line. The data will always be the same? If not, how how should the files be merged?

Comment: Also, you should consider adding some tags to the question, regarding the tools you want to use to merge the files. On my answer I used notepad++ because of the other question you asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following procedure with notepad++:

1. Go to file1 and add some data that cannot be found on the lines (for example `@@@@@`) at the beggining of each line with following regex replace: search (regex): `^` Replace by: `@@@@@`. After that, first file should look like this:

   ```
   @@@@@Firstline
   @@@@@ABCD
   @@@@@Thirdline
   @@@@@
   @@@@@Fifthine
   ```
2. Go to second file and select (as columns) all data. You can do this placing at the beggining of the file and the ALT+SHIFT+(END, PAGEUP)
3. Control+C for copy
4. Go to first file, place at the beggining and paste with Control+V. The first file now should look like this:

   ```
   Firstline@@@@@Firstline
   @@@@@ABCD
   Thirdline@@@@@Thirdline
   EFGH@@@@@
   Fifthline@@@@@Fifthine
   ```
5. Do a search and replace: Search (regex): `^@@@@@|@@@@@[^\n\r]*` Replace: `(nothing)`. The first file will be:

   ```
   Firstline
   ABCD
   Thirdline
   EFGH
   Fifthline
   ```

Comment: Hey, thank you again for helping me. This is what I was looking for.